# twitter4j.TwitterException: 401:Authentication credentials were missing or incorrect

Tags: java, gwt, twitter

I am developing web based application in Java [GWT] 
I am facing problem with TwitterException.
I used valid  credential.
Twitter twitter = new Twitter(myTwitterId, myTwiterPwd); 
when I call twitter.getFollowers() method

I got following Error Message

```
twitter4j.TwitterException: 401:Authentication credentials were missing or incorrect.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<errors>
    <error code="53">Basic authentication is not supported</error>
</errors>

    at twitter4j.http.HttpClient.httpRequest(HttpClient.java:469)
    at twitter4j.http.HttpClient.get(HttpClient.java:412)
    at twitter4j.Twitter.get(Twitter.java:276)
    at twitter4j.Twitter.get(Twitter.java:228)
    at twitter4j.Twitter.getFollowersStatuses(Twitter.java:1363)
    at twitter4j.Twitter.getFollowers(Twitter.java:1350)
    at com.vaibhav.dealelephant.server.impl.TwitterServiceImpl.getTwitterFollowers(TwitterServiceImpl.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:562)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:188)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:224)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:286)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:845)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

I want to display My followers Images into My Website, but it throws exception after calling this method **twitter.getFollowers()** method. SO unable to get My follwers Images :(

Please provide me Easy solution for the same

Hope for the best co-operation from your side

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: What version of twitter4j are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, your authentication is not working because Twitter made some recent changes
regarding how it lets 3rd party code authenticate.

- http://news.techworld.com/security/3237604/twitter-turns-on-oauth-api-authentication/
- http://www.networkworld.com/news/2010/083110-twitter-api-has-new-third.html?hpg1=bn
- http://www.wired.com/epicenter/2010/08/twitter-login-errors/
- http://groups.google.com/group/twitter-api-announce/browse_thread/thread/f71eb68600996af8

In other words, Basic authentication has been turned off for the API.

- https://apiwiki.twitter.com/Authentication

As Allain mentions, oAuth is the way to go.

Comment: Instead of passing id & pwd to Twitter can we just pass twitterid, twitter = new Twitter(myTwitterId);  It will work or not ?

Answer (score 3):

The code you posted is different than what I've seen in the past for connecting. I think (though I'm not sure) that oAuth is the preferred way of authenticating now.

[Here's a blog that details using oAuth to connect.](http://jeungun.wordpress.com/2009/09/03/quick-and-dirty-twitter4j-oauth-for-web-apps/)

Comment: and another: http://marvinlee.net/blog/2010/03/free-java-twitter-api-twitter4j-and-oauth/

Answer (score 0):

I was having that trouble, finally the solution was to put a valid Callback url in my twitter API at (https://dev.twitter.com/‎),  I used google+ url, saved changes (it could take a minutes before the changes are made, refresh the page to be sure) and it worked.